# The 'number' property on 'Employee' could not be set to a 'System.Decimal' value

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

The 'number' property on 'Employee' could not be set to a 'System.Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Double'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
       Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The 'number' property 
on 'Employee' could not be set to a 'System.Decimal' value. You must set this 
property to a non-null value of type 'System.Double'.
```

Source Error:

```
    Line 16:         {
    Line 17:             EmployeeContext empcon = new EmployeeContext();
    Line 18:             Employee employ = empcon.employees.Single(emp => emp.empid ==  
    id);
    Line 19:             return View(employ);
    Line 20:         }
```

Please anyone help me

```
[Table("tbl_employee")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key]public int empid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set;}
    public double number { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeContext :DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> employees  { get; set; }
}
```

**View**:

```
  @model Employee_data.Models.Employee
  @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Emloyee Details";
  }

  <h2>Emloyee Details</h2>
  <table style="font-family:Arial">
  <tr>

 <td>
<b>employee id</b>
 </td>
  <td>@Model.empid</td>
 </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
   <b>employee Name</b>
</td>
<td>@Model.name</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
     <b>employee address</b>
     </td>
     <td>@Model.Address</td>
      </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>
        <b>employee number</b>
      </td>
    <td>@Model.number</td>
          </tr>
          </table>
       @Html.ActionLink("click me", "Details", new { id = "1" })
```

**Global.asax**:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        Database.SetInitializer<Employee_data.Models.EmployeeContext>(null);
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
        EmployeeContext empcon = new EmployeeContext();
        Employee employ = empcon.employees.Single(emp => emp.empid == id);
        return View(employ);
}
```

`web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=Testdb;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Route config:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "emp", action = "Details", 
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
```

Comment: please show us url u have called

Comment: could any help me for better solution, where i done mistake,i didn't find

Answer (score 1):

Set it to Decimal

```
[Key]
public int empid { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set;}
public Decimal number { get; set; }
```

I think it will work..
try this one..

Answer (score 0):

> This error is thrown if you attempt to call this controller action and
>   you do not specify the id either in the path portion or as query
>   string parameter. Since your controller action takes an id as
>   parameter you should make sure that you always specify this parameter.
>
> Make sure that when you are requesting this action you have specified
>   a valid id in the url:

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344385/mvc-3-exception-the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter)

If `empid` is your key try this

```
[Key] public int empid{ get; set; }
```

Comment: then why dont u define key for employee table.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2011/05/04/entity-framework-code-first-tutorial-supplement-what-is-going-on-in-a-fluent-api-call.aspx first learn about entity framework and then move to coding

Comment: please check what the primary key in your table and map table to class correctly

Comment: so definr it as a key

Comment: well, i cant say from here whats the iisue is so please surf on web, learn the base os technology u r using and then only apply coding

Comment: but if you get knowledge then only you can apply it in ur code. otherwise you are going to stuck, i am not saying that getting stucked is bad but search form the issue you are facing you definitely will get solution.